# Visa-free travel to the US using refugee travel document from Spain?

Tags: usa, spain, refugees

Can my friend who is a refugee travel document holder from Spain come to the U.S. with/without a visa?

Answer (score 9):

No.  Your friend requires a visa to come to the US.

Citizens of Spain can come to the US without a visa under the [Visa Waiver Program](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visa-waiver-program.html), but one criterion for participating in the VWP is to have the nationality of, and present a passport issued by, a VWP country ([8 USC 1187(a)(2)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1187#a_2)).  Your friend is therefore unable to come to the US under the VWP even if he or she has the nationality of a VWP country, because refugees are generally unable to use a passport issued by their country of nationality.

The US embassy in Spain and Andorra has a [page about visas](https://es.usembassy.gov/visas/) that would serve as a good starting point to get more information about how to apply.